# CRichEditCtrl loads Unicode text incorrectly

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, mfc

I use CRichEditCtrl in my dialog, but when I pasted in it copied Vietnamese text, the text doesn't display correct text; odd characters are displayed where the 2 byte encoded characters are shown.

Has any one run into this problem before? How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using an appropriate font?

Comment: Have you tried other multi-byte languages?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using font like `Arial Unicode MS` which has Unicode characters for multi language support. Use `CWnd::SetFont` with your `CRichEditCtrl` object in `CDialog::OnInitDialog`. For creating font have an object of type `CFont`. Create font using `CFont::CreatePointFont` or `CFont::CreateFont` method.